# parsing xml from within MATLAB

Tags: xml, matlab

```
<root>
   <file name="C:\...toto.txt">
      <function name="foo" size="0">
         <kind name="arg1" color="red" allowed="yes" value="1..2"/>
         <source name="text" allowed="no" />
      </function>

   </file>
   <file name="C:\\...\\tata.txt">
      <function name="foo" size="25">
         <kind name="arg2" color="red" allowed="yes" value="1..5"/>
         <source name="text" allowed="no" />
      </function>

   </file>
   <file name="C:\\..\\titi.txt">
      <function name="foo" size="60">
         <kind name="arg3" color="green" allowed="no" value="0"/>
         <source name="text" allowed="no" />
      </function>

   </file>
</root>
```

I need to get the value of arg3 from titi.txt ?

I've tried :

```
xmlFile = xmlread(myFile);
xmlFile.getElementsByTagName('file')
```

How could I continue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the function name suggests, `getElementsByTagName` returns a list - which in your case will contain all file-tags.

You can loop trough that list, find `titi.txt` and get its attributes:

```java
xmlFile = xmlread(myFile);
files = xmlFile.getElementsByTagName('file');
for iF=1:files.getLength()
    f = files.item(iF-1);
    % the filename
    if strcmp(char(f.getAttribute('name')), 'C:\...titi.txt')
        % here you'll have to further recurse into the children
        % of f, e.g. starting with:
        kinds = f.getElementsByTagName('kind');
        % get the first element and its value-attribute
    end
end
```

An certainly faster alternative would be to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

It is somewhat less easy to understand at might take a little more time to get it working, but it has the huge benefit of doing all the looping/filtering logic for you.
Which is especially useful in MATLAB since those things are slow here.

```
factory = javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance();
xpath = factory.newXPath();
% prepare the xpath-query for your use-case:
% get a file under the root element with specified name, the function element beneath
% and finally the value-attribute of the kind-element:
expr = xpath.compile('/root//file[@name=''C:\...titi.txt'']/function/kind/@value');

% evaluate the query - xmlFile is the same as above
% the second argument specifies the return-type - in this case, a simple java-string containing the value of the "value" attribute:
value = expr.evaluate(xmlFile, javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING); 
% convert to MATLAB char:
value = char(value);
```

**EDIT:**

To make this a more general solution, you can easily generate the query-string in a variable manner:

```
query = sprintf('/root//file[@name=''%s'']/function/kind/@value', yourFileNameHere);
expr = xpath.comile(query);
```

Comment: is there a way to say file that contains titi.txt , as I would like to do make it generic

Comment: Sure - simply assemble the xpath query dynamically, see my modifed answer. If this solved your problem, please accept my answer :)

Comment: ok sebastian, I think that the problem comes from double slash C:\\..\\titi.txt, I've updated the problem. I don't think if there are a function similar to 'replace' ?

Comment: There is `strrep`. But I'm not sure I understand the problem. If there are double slashes in the xml, you can also put the double-slash into `query` and it should work fine. Or would you like to change the xml, replacing double-slash with one slash?

Comment: just I don't want to add path "hard" but do it dynamycally

Comment: myFile = C:\...\titi.txt , in the xml ,it contains \\ slash

Comment: Well, if there are two slashs in the xml, you'll have to search accordingly. You could e.g. do `myFileSearch = strrep(myFile, '\', '\\');` Then use `myFileSearch` for the `query` instead of `myFile`.